# Add color of each pixel to ArrayList - java

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

**I want to add the red-Value of each pixel of an** `Image` **to an** `ArrayList`**.**

This is my code:

```
BufferedImage image = null;
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ArrayList<List<List<Integer>>> colors = new ArrayList<List<List<Integer>>>();

    for ( int i = 0; i < image.getHeight(); i++ ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < image.getWidth(); j++ ) {
            colors.get(i).get(j).add(new Color(image.getRGB(i, j)).getRed());
        }
    }
```

But I get this error: `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0`.

**What do I do wrong?**

Comment: You are trying to access items inside `colors` but you haven't put anything inside it yet. `colors.get(i)`

Comment: @csmckelvey How do I do that?

Comment: Why do you have a list of lists of lists (i.e. a 3D array) in the first place? All those inner lists won't be created magically. You need to create them, and add them to their enclosing list.

Comment: You should initialize your list like List<Color> colors=new ArrayList<>(); and add elements on it like colors.add(new Color(....));

Comment: Add items to an ArrayList? I'm sure you can find info about that - no need for a stackoverflow question for that.

Comment: @JBNizet I want to have each column seperated and I want each pixel to be seperated too because I want to add both red, green, blue and alpha later on.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you only need a list of lists to represent the 2d nature of the pixels (you currency have a list of list of lists).  Each time you iterate over each pixel of height you should create a new as shown below.

```
   List<List<Integer>> colors = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

   for ( int i = 0; i < image.getHeight(); i++ ) {
        List<Integer> rowOfColours = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        colors.add(rowOfColors);

        for ( int j = 0; j < image.getWidth(); j++ ) {
            rowOfColours.add(new Color(image.getRGB(i, j)).getRed());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PillHead's answer. If later you want to get the whole pixel then slightly alter the code to:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < image.getHeight(); i++ ) {
    List<Integer> rowOfPixelData = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    colors.add(rowOfPixelData);

    for ( int j = 0; j < image.getWidth(); j++ ) {
        rowOfPixelData.add(image.getRGB(i, j));
    }
}
```

From there you can extract the values you want. [This website](https://www.dyclassroom.com/image-processing-project/how-to-get-and-set-pixel-value-in-java) has lots of good information on how to get the Red, Green, Blue, and Alpha values from the integer returned by `image.getRGB(i, j)`.